# Covariant and Contravariant Functor of Fixed Set Question - Category of Sets

Tags: category-theory

I am very new to Category Theory and am currently working on a simple question, I know I'm wrong, just wanted to know HOW wrong I am in my answer:

**Question:**

"Verify for Fixed set A, the operations  $ X\mapsto  X^A $ and $ X\mapsto  A^X $ are, respectively, covariant and contravariant functors on the Category of Sets."

**Attempted Answer:**

$ X^A$ and $A^X$ are opposite of each other, represented by $f:A \rightarrow X$ and $h:X \rightarrow A$, thus, if A is fixed, we can say that $X^A$ is covariant by $hom(A,-):C\rightarrow Set$ and $A^X$ is contravariant by $hom(-,X):{C^o}^p \rightarrow Set$. I assume that the $X$ element-maps to each of the set of functions but I have no idea what else are they used for except to indicate that the $X$ for the former and latter terms are in the **codomain** and **domain** of the functions respectively.

Go easy pl0x. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is imprecise. After all, the formulae $X \mapsto X^A$ and $X \mapsto A^X$ do not specify what happens to morphisms. The point is to define actual functors whose object parts are as specified – so there's really nothing much to it at all.

Comment: The question was taken from a problem set of Steve Awodey's Summer program session in Oregon '12. It may be the case that students were expected to be well acquainted with category theory already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with $X\mapsto X^A$, we can denote this functor, by the notation you use in your answer, as $\def\hom{\mathord{\rm hom}}\hom(A,-)$. We have to prove, that it is a functor $\def\S{\mathord{\sf Set}}\S \to \S$. Let's recall how it is defined: For a set $X$, we have 
$$ \hom(A,-)(X) = X^A = \{f \mid f \colon A \to X \} $$
the set of functions from $A$ to $X$, and for a map $f \colon X \to Y$, the map 
$$ \hom(A, f) = f^A \colon X^A \to Y^A $$ 
is given by $\hom(A, f)(g) = f \circ g$ for all $g \colon A \to X$.

To prove that $\hom(A,-)$ is a functor, first note that for $f \colon X \to Y$, $g \colon Y \to Z$ and any $h \in X^A$ we have
\begin{align*}
  \hom(A, g \circ f)(h) &= (g \circ f)\circ h\\
      &= g \circ (f \circ h)\\
      &= \hom(A, g)(f \circ h)\\
      &= \bigl(\hom(A,g) \circ \hom(A,f)\bigr)(h)\\
\end{align*}
Hence, as $h$ was arbitrary, 
$$ \hom(A, g \circ f) = \hom(A, g) \circ \hom(A,f ) $$
On the other hand, for ${\rm id}_X\colon X \to X$ and any $h \in X^A$ we have
$$ \hom(A, \def\i{{\rm id}}\i_X)(h) = h \circ \i_X = h = \i_{\hom(A,X)}(h) $$
that is 
$$ \hom(A, \i_X) = \i_{\hom(A,X)} $$
So, $\hom(A,-)$ is a (covariant) functor.

For $\hom(-,A)\colon X \mapsto A^X$, the proof works almost along the same lines, using the definitions 
$$ \hom(-,A)(X) = A^X, \qquad \hom(f,A)\colon A^Y \ni h \mapsto h \circ f \in A^X,\quad f \colon X \to Y $$
We have
$$ \hom(f\circ g, A) = \hom(g,A) \circ \hom(f,A), \quad \hom(\i_X, A) = \i_{\hom(X,A)} $$
proving that $\hom(-,A) \colon \S^{\rm op} \to \S$ is a functor.

Comment: So just to be sure, the composition of relations and identity of the hom functor determines the covariance/contravariance, the fixed A applies to both X^A and A^X (hence i was wrong in that aspect), the contravariant hom(f,A) = A^Y -> A^X. With regards to contravariance, for hom(f o g, A), what is g is this case?